# How do I see the arguments (and types) of a python method?

Tags: python, class, function, twitter, methods

```
$ py twitterDump2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitterDump2.py", line 30, in <module>
    stream=tweepy.Stream(username,password,listener)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

My code:

```
username="abc"
password="abc"
listener = StreamWatcherListener()
stream=tweepy.Stream(username,password,listener)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to __init__ is usually self so it is expecting you to pass only two arguments.

Surprising the tweepy.streaming.py code suggests:

```
class Stream(object):

    host = 'stream.twitter.com'

    def __init__(self, auth, listener, **options):
        self.auth = auth
        self.listener = listener
```

The auth is created this way:

```
auth = tweepy.BasicAuthHandler(username, password)
```

Your code should be something like this

```
username="abc"
password="abc"
listener = StreamWatcherListener()
auth = tweepy.BasicAuthHandler(username, password)
stream=tweepy.Stream(auth,listener)
```

See the code at : http://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py

Comment: Thanks!! But, in the future, how do I know what argument types it accepts?

Comment: @TIMEX: See my edited answer. The auth is created using username and password and then the same is passed on to tweepy.Stream

Comment: @TIMEX: PulFiction answers your question on how to find things. Use help() function and also the code is easy to read. just do that. Nothing to shy away from :)

Answer (score 2):

pyfunc has given the reasons why this is not working.

To see what arguments, type:

`help(tweepy.Stream)`

This will give you what arguments the Stream class requires.

This is for your reference:

```
def __init__(self, auth, listener, **options)
```

`options` takes a dictionary that delivers keywords arguments with the ** operator.

Comment: Aah! I was replying to his question as to how to see arguments of a Python method :)